# How to open a local executable from browser sharepoint

Tags: exe, sharepoint-online

So, we're using SharePoint as a hub, and we'd like to open a local executable for a training application that is on all PCs using a quick link or a button on the SharePoint. the issue comes from SharePoint not allowing us to run the executable.

I've tried HTA, Batch files, power automate. I've tried just loading the executable into the SharePoint files and running it from there. with HTA batch and SharePoint files, the link just opens in the browser just opens it as readable or tries to download the link. power automate desktop let me build the write code, but it then can't link to the share point as it's running from desktop and the browser edition doesn't have the right capabilities.